# Build a List<T> from a String

Tags: java, casting, java-stream

I am trying to make a generic function that builds a List of any type based on a string that holds values of that type delimited by let's say a comma. I have done this:

```
public static <T> List<T> stringToList(String listStr, Class<T> itemType)
{
    return Arrays.asList(listStr.split(",")).stream().map(x -> itemType.cast(x.replaceAll("\\s+|\"|\t","")))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When I try to test it with:

```
String listStringsStr  = "\"Foo\", \"Bar\"";
List<String> resS = stringToList(listStringsStr, String.class);

String listIntegersStr = "1,10,-1,0";
List<Integer> resI = stringToList(listStringsStr, Integer.class);
```

I have two problems.

1. In the first case (String) I get an extra double quote around each string item: ""Foo"", ""Bar"".
2. In the second case (Integer) I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer` which means that it can't convert "1" to 1. I know this works with `Integer::parseInt`, but I want to make a generic method.

Any Ideas?

[EDIT] - Because I caused confusion the way I posted it, I add the test code:

```
String listStringsStr  = "\"Foo\", \"Bar\"";
List<String> listStrings = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
String listIntegersStr = "1,10,-1,0";
List<Integer> listIntegers = Arrays.asList(1, 10, -1, 0);

List<String> resS = stringToList(listStringsStr, String.class);
System.out.println(resS);
System.out.println(listStrings);
assert (resS.containsAll(listStrings));

List<Integer> resI = stringToList(listIntegersStr, Integer.class);
System.out.println(resI);
System.out.println(listIntegers);
assert (resI.containsAll(listIntegers));
```

After including the `x.replaceAll("\\s+|\"|\t","")` the first assertion now pass, the second fails. The console output is

```
[Foo, Bar]
[Foo, Bar]
[1, 10, -1, 0]
[1, 10, -1, 0]
```

listIntegers holds Integer thus I suppose resI holds ints, or I just broke java's type safety :D

Comment: No, you don't have extra quotes. The only quotes you have are the ones that are in the string. Printing resS shows `resS = ["Foo",  "Bar"]`.

Comment: I have. When you print a String in the console the quotes are removed:
        List<String> listStrings = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
        assert (resS.containsAll(listStrings));
raises an Exception showing that listStrings contain ["Foo", "Bar"] where resS contains [""Foo"", ""Bar""].
If you print listStrings you will see no quotes

Comment: @chefarov If your definition is that values are comma-separated, and nothing else, then the quotes are *part of* the value. This even includes the leading space before `"Bar"`. If you want quotes to be used to allow value to contain commas, then you need to CSV Parser, not a plain `split()`, since that is CSV syntax, which is more than just comma-separating.

Comment: @Andreas you are right I added a regex to remove unwanted characters

Comment: Don’t use Chad Dienhart’s solution, it still returns a list of String, just pretending to be a `List<T>` due to the unchecked type cast. The expression `itemType.toString().valueOf(…)` is pure nonsense. And, further, *don’t* copy answers into your question. The answer are already there, nobody needs a copy of them inside your question.

Comment: @Holger you are right I understood that afterwards

Answer (score 6):

For problem #2: A simple modification would be to pass a `Function<String, T>` instead of `Class<T>`. The function would define how to parse the string as the class of the desired type. Some possible values:

```
Function<String, String> stringParser = s -> s;
Function<String, Integer> intParser = s -> Integer.parseInt(s);
```

For problem #1: In the example you gave the input strings *do* contain quotes. You could have made the input string `"Foo,Bar"` to avoid having quotes in the output. If you don't have control over the input, you can trim quotes/whitespace/etc. as part of the parsing function, or separate the words by something more advanced than splitting by commas - is the input a CSV file?

Comment: Additional suggestion: To allow string representation of object to include comma, use a CSV parser instead of `split()`, so quoting can be used to support embedded commas.

Comment: There should be a simpler solution than passing a conversion function as argument to another conversion function. At least there is in any other language I know

Comment: Well, it depends on the contents of your input string. Clearly it can contain strings. What about numbers, lists, maps, or more complex objects? Are they lines from a CSV file?

Comment: Well, first you are converting a `String` to an array of Strings and then you are converting a `String` to a specific type. There are two different conversions that have to be addressed and are necessary. Also, the solution is not that hard, you just do a `function.apply(x)` and then pass a Lambda expression as a call, like: `stringToList(listStringsStr, (s) -> { return Integer.parseInt(s); });`

Comment: @chefarov Your question said *"any type"*, so how would you expect generic code to know how to create an instance of my custom `Train` class (as an example) from a `String`, unless you either explicitly allow me to provide a parser, or assume that my class has a `String` constructor?

Comment: @guitarsteve Suggestion for answer (problem #2): Show the effect of your suggestion, i.e. the second argument of `stringToList` in the two examples would be `String::toString` and `Integer::parseInt`, respectively.

Comment: @Andreas sry I meant the simple classes representing primitive types

Comment: @Andreas thanks - I added examples. I figured explicit lambdas make it more clear how to extend the examples than method references.

Comment: @chefarov: making the function work for a predefined set of classes is possible, but where’s the sense in that premise? For the caller, `Integer.class` is not simpler than `Integer::valueOf`, and semantically, you are passing a function in both cases, just using different forms, whereas the `Class` form requires some kind of Reflection to invoke it.

Comment: If I pass     intParser to     stringToList, replacing     x -> itemType.cast(x) with     map(intParser) , I get an
"Error:(26, 32) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: T
    equality constraints(s): T,java.lang.Integer "

Comment: @Holger. Yeah I suppose that finally this function may not be much meaningfull at all